# Cannot use an nginx container to use port 80 on Mac

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a dockerized nginx container on port 80 on my Mac Sonoma 14.4:

`sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 myapp_frontend:0.0.1`

There are no error messages when running the container, but upon checking, there is already something that is using port 80 (and 443), if I navigate to http://localhost (or localhost:443), I get a message `404 page not found`.

I tried turning off all containers, and with all containers turned off, port 80 (and 443) was still in use, so I tried `sudo lsof -i :80` and it says that ssh is using port 80

```
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ssh     55827 doge   39u  IPv4 0x5b39b294bb888101      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

How can I be able to map port 80 for my docker container?

EDIT:
on further investigation, this seems to be related with apachectl:

```
apachectl status
Go to http://localhost:80/server-status in the web browser of your choice.
Note that mod_status must be enabled for this to work.
```